# C# from Client Windows application download Server SSL Certificate from Server (Hostname & Port Provided)

Tags: c#, https, ssl-certificate

I have C# Client windows application, and I have Server Hostname and Port details.  So from Clienat application I want to download Server SSL certificate.  How can I download it from Client?

Please help!!

Areef

Comment: What protocol do you plan to use?